# How can I make file download slower?

Tags: php

This is  my [final download](http://www.downloadformsindia.com/index.php?option=com_download&e=n&task=showpage&file=Forms/Income-Tax/AY2010-11/ITR-1/form-20itr-1_001.doc&title=Income%20Tax%20ITR-1%28New%20Saral%202%29%20Form%202010%3aMS%20Word%20format&code=igi) page of my website where general public is able to download govt documents. From server my code is reading the to-be-downloaded-file and in a loop sending to the client browser.

```
$fp = fopen($file, "rb");
    while (!feof($fp))
    {
        echo fread($fp, 65536);
        flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
    }
    fclose($fp);
    exit;
```

I want to send the file very slowly -- that is can I use Sleep function (or anything like that)  within this loop and by how much maximum without causing the user client browser to timeout?
So that the user gets sufficient time to read the ads displayed on the page while he/she awaits for the file download to finish.
Also I'm not proficient with PHP environment.
(Pl. fogive me for the morality/immorality of this).

Comment: Well, ad revenue aside, if these are government documents, they MUST be available elsewhere, and if you slow the downloads down, eventually, people will figure out other ways of getting them.  And then you won't have ANY ad revenue....

Comment: People in India try their best to avoid govt sites.

Answer (score 3):

Try this approach: http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/341922-using-php-limit-download-speed

Comment: For this link I understand I can add sleep(1); in the code. My question is can I make it 2 or 3 seconds or more without causing the client browser to timeout?

Comment: @user656848 Increasing the sleep wouldn't be the best way to change the speed of the download, instead modify the `$speed` variable in that example that affects the fread. This gives you more control of what you want to do.

Comment: The $speed variable changes the data size read/sent each time. To reduce the speed if I make it send smaller chunks won't it increase the burden on the server? I'd like to send data in an "optimized" way -- also minimizing the resource used.

Comment: I could be that this will decrease performance. To be sure i think you will have to set up a test that measures this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bandwidth sharing](http://www.topology.org/src/bwshare/README.html) if you're willing to do this at the Apache level.